# Filter out closest duplicated rows (but not completely all) from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, grouping

In table I need to filter out nearest duplicated rows which have same `status_id` (but not completely all) when `user_id` is the same. `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` did not help in this situation. Here is an example:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id  |  user_id | status_id | date               |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1  |    10    |    1      | 2010-10-10 10:00:10|
|  2  |    10    |    1      | 2010-10-11 10:00:10|
|  3  |    10    |    1      | 2010-10-12 10:00:10|
|  4  |    10    |    2      | 2010-10-13 10:00:10|
|  5  |    10    |    4      | 2010-10-14 10:00:10|
|  6  |    10    |    4      | 2010-10-15 10:00:10|
|  7  |    10    |    2      | 2010-10-16 10:00:10|
|  8  |    10    |    2      | 2010-10-17 10:00:10|
|  9  |    10    |    1      | 2010-10-18 10:00:10|
|  10 |    10    |    1      | 2010-10-19 10:00:10|
```

Have to look like:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id  |  user_id | status_id | date               |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1  |    10    |    1      | 2010-10-10 10:00:10|
|  4  |    10    |    2      | 2010-10-13 10:00:10|
|  5  |    10    |    4      | 2010-10-14 10:00:10|
|  7  |    10    |    2      | 2010-10-16 10:00:10|
|  9  |    10    |    1      | 2010-10-18 10:00:10|
```

Oldest entries (by date) should remain in the table

Comment: JFYI, phpmyadmin and mysqli has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to keep each row where the previous status is different, based on the `id` or `date` column.

If your ids are really sequential (as they are in the question), you can do this with a convenient join:

```
select t.*
from t left outer join
     t tprev
     on t.id = tprev.id+1
where tprev.id is null or tprev.status <> t.status;
```

If the ids are not sequential, you can get the previous one using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.status
              from t t2
              where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                    t2.id < t.id
              order by t2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prevstatus
      from t
     ) t
where prevstatus is null or prevstatus <> t.status;
```

Comment: I have tried second query with not sequential ids and it seems that this query is loading to infinity. Table name is `veh_vehicle_history` it has maybe I have messed up with this `t` names.

Comment: @DeividasJJ . . . Performance will be improved by having an index on `(user_id, id, status)`.

Comment: @DeividasJJ . . . One composite index with all three columns, in the order given.